# Variadic template expansion with aliases?

Tags: c++, templates, alias, c++20

So in a codebase I inherited we have a messy utility file along the lines of:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) == 1)>> int doA(const T *Data, size_t Size);
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) == 1)>> int doB(const T *Data, size_t Size);

template <typename T> int doA(T &Input) 
{ return doA<uint8_t>((uint8_t *)&Input, sizeof(T); };
template <typename T, size_t N> int doA(T(&Input)[N]) 
{ return doA(Input, N - 1); };

template <typename T> int doA(std::vector<T> Input) 
{ return doA((uint8_t *)Input.data(), sizeof(T::value_type) * Input.size()); };
/* Repeat for doB */
```

So I figured that since `doA` and `doB` were pretty similar, one could reduce the mess to:

```
template <bool TypeA, typename T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) == 1)>> 
int do_t(const T *Data, size_t Size) { if constexpr(TypeA) ... };

template <bool TypeA, typename T> int do_t(T &Input) 
{ return do_t<TypeA, uint8_t>((uint8_t *)&Input, sizeof(T); };
template <bool TypeA, typename T, size_t N> int do_t(T(&Input)[N]) 
{ return do_t<TypeA, T>(Input, N - 1); };

template <bool TypeA, typename T> int do_t(std::vector<T> Input) 
{ return do_t<TypeA, uint8_t>((uint8_t *)Input.data(), sizeof(T::value_type) * Input.size()); };

template <typename ...Args> using doA = do_t<true, Args...>;
template <typename ...Args> using doB = do_t<false, Args...>;

// Expand to do_t<true, char, 4>(char (&Input)[4])
static_assert(doA("abc") == 123);

// Expand to do_t<false, int>(int &Input)
static_assert(doB(321) == 123);
```

Naturally that didn't work out with the compiler complaining that `do_t` is undefined at the alias. What's the proper approach to something like this where you want to capture all overloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that, instead of your couple of `using` declarations, you can write a couple of C-style macros.

But I consider C-style macros as distilled evil, so I propose two simple conversion functions

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto doA (Args && ... as)
 { return do_t<true>(std::forward<Args>(as)...); }

template <typename ... Args>
auto doB (Args && ... as)
 { return do_t<false>(std::forward<Args>(as)...); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might use functor object:

```
template <bool isA>
struct doT
{
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) == 1), int> = 0> 
    int operator()(const T *Data, size_t Size) const
    {
        if constexpr (isA) { return doA_impl(Data, Size); }
        else { return doB_impl(Data, Size); }
    }

    template <typename T>
    int operator() (T &Input) const
    { return (*this)((std::uint8_t *)&Input, sizeof(T)); }

    template <typename T, size_t N>
    int operator() (T(&Input)[N]) const
    { return (*this)(Input, N - 1); }

    template <typename T>
    int operator() (std::vector<T> Input) const
    { return (*this)((std::uint8_t *)Input.data(), sizeof (T::value_type) * Input.size()); };
};

constexpr doT<true> doA{};
constexpr doT<false> doB{};
```

Note: ADL won't work for functor objects contrary to regular functions.